# Why does FindSequenceFunction not work in this case?

Tags: functions

Why does this not work?

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1/2, (2/3)^2, (3/4)^4, (4/5)^6, (5/6)^8}, n]
(*FindSequenceFunction[{1/2,4/9,81/256,4096/15625,390625/1679616},n]*)
```

I thought `(n/(n + 1))^(2 n - 2)` but unfortunately the first number isn't correct.
Except the first number, I expect all the following numbers are of the form `(n/(n + 1))^(2 n - 2)`.

Comment: Help says `attempts to find a simple function that yields the sequence Subscript[a, n]` note the word _attempts_, which means it might not be able to find such a function. May be it needs more terms? May be there is no such function?  But I see some weakness in this function, Here is an easier one it could not find `f[n_] := (n/(n + 1))^(n); Table[f[n], {n, 1, 10}]` and now `FindGeneratingFunction[%, n]` could not find the function   `(n/(n + 1))^(n)` which generates this sequence. I tried more terms, it still could not find it.

Comment: @Nasser I see. Is there a better function for this?

Comment: I do not know of alternative. May be someone will have better idea what is going on and if there is a workaround.

Comment: When `FindSequenceFuntion` fails, the next step is to try oeis.org.  That website also deals with fractions that are rational numbers.  While it doesn't have that particular sequence (or the one that @Nasser mentioned), one of the hints (http://oeis.org/hints.html) is to enter the numerators and denominators separately.  For these two cases, that gives enough information to find the sequence function.

Answer (score 8):

Consider the sequence given by @Nasser in the comments above:

```
seq = Table[(n/(n + 1))^(n), {n, 1, 10}]
```

[image: Sequence]

Find the sequences of the numerators and denominators:

```
numerators = Numerator[seq]
(* {1, 4, 27, 256, 3125, 46656, 823543, 16777216, 387420489, 10000000000} *)
denominators = Denominator[seq]
(* {2, 9, 64, 625, 7776, 117649, 2097152, 43046721, 1000000000, 25937424601} *)
```

(A hint given at oeis.org is to look at the numerator and denominator sequences separately.)

Use `FindSequenceFunction` on the numerators:

```
FindSequenceFunction[numerators, n]
(* n^n *)
```

Now on the denominators:

```
FindSequenceFunction[denominators, n]
(* FindSequenceFunction[{2, 9, 64, 625, 7776, 117649, 2097152, 43046721, 1000000000, 25937424601}, n] *)
```

But just the input is returned.  So check this sequence at oeis.org and we find that one of the generators of those numbers is

```
n^(n-1)
```

If we produce the first 10 values from that result we see

```
Table[n^(n - 1), {n, 1, 10}]
(* {1, 2, 9, 64, 625, 7776, 117649, 2097152, 43046721, 1000000000} *)
```

We need the first term to be 2 rather than 1:

```
Table[(n + 1)^n, {n, 1, 10}]
(* {2, 9, 64, 625, 7776, 117649, 2097152, 43046721, 1000000000, 25937424601} *)
```

Now putting the numerator and denominator functions together we have

```
n^n/(n+1)^n
```

or

```
(n/(n+1))^n
```

which is the formula that generated the sequence.

For the OP's original problem `FindSequenceFunction` doesn't work and for the denominator the first term doesn't "fit".  However, skipping the first term and searching for the numerator and denominator sequences at oeis.org does work and one can then construct a formula for the OP's sequence.

***Addition:***

If one had many sequences in *Mathematica* to check at oeis.org, then the following function will at least report "At least one sequence found." or "Sorry, couldn't find sequence."  One would still have to go to oeis.org to look at the positive hits.

```
checkOEIS[sequence_] := Module[{html, string},
  (* Change ", " to "%2C" *)
  string = StringReplace[ToString[sequence], ", " -> "%2C"];
  (* Remove curly brackets *)
  string = StringTake[string, {2, StringLength[string] - 1}];
  (* Get report *)
  html = Import["https://oeis.org/search?q=" <> string <>  "&language=english&go=Search"];
  (* If "Sorry" is in the received text, then there is no corresponding sequence found *)
  If[StringPosition[html, "Sorry, but the terms"] == List[], 
   Print["At least one sequence found."], 
   Print["Sorry, couldn't find sequence."]]
  ]

checkOEIS[{1, 2, 3, 4}]
(* At least one sequence found. *)
```

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[Table[n^(2 n - 2), {n, 1, 12}], n]` returns the input.

Comment: @user64494 oeis.org does find the generating function for that sequence.

Comment: JimB (@ does not work.): Sorry, OEIS is not a Mathematica tool.

Comment: @user64494 Yes but one piece of software doesn't do everything (although Mathematica can certainly do a lot). A valid solution to any question posed at this forum might very well include calls to R, the operating system, etc.  What I proposed did use *Mathematica* for half of the solution.  Had I only used oeis.org, then my answer would have been better as a comment and I would agree with your assessment.

Comment: JimB: Mathematica may execute `C++` and `R` codes, but can't programmatically  find and extract sequences from OEIS.

Comment: @user64494  You are correct.  But I've added a simple helper function if one had many sequences from within *Mathematica* to check.

Answer (score 4):

```
seq = {1/2, (2/3)^2, (3/4)^4, (4/5)^6, (5/6)^8};
```

As you point out, the powers are not easily represented and [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) is not able to handle this case without help. The sequence is

```
x[n_] = (n/(n + 1))^FindSequenceFunction[{1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, n]
```

[image]

```
% // InputForm

(* (n/(1 + n))^DifferenceRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalN]}, 
    {-2 - \[FormalY][\[FormalN]] + \[FormalY][1 + \[FormalN]] == 0, 
     \[FormalY][1] == 1, \[FormalY][2] == 2}]][n] *)

Table[x[n], {n, Length[seq]}] === seq

(* True )
```